# Do twitter links adversely affect SEO?

Tags: seo, links, twitter

I had planned on making a page according to a specific theme using content populated from the Twitter search API. 
With the new [display requirements](https://dev.twitter.com/terms/display-requirements), I see I am obliged to include hash links, twitter username links and a lot of other garbage links.

**QUESTION**

- Are these links likely to adversely affect my page's SEO?
- If yes, are there any ways I can minimise that (ie. add no follow or
  such).

Comment: I will add a simple `rel="nofollow"` to all links, the same Twitter does for external client on the web client (before they remove them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ungodly amount of spam passes through Twitter unfiltered so if you are displaying raw tweets then you should add nofollow to them. Linking out to very spammy sites could harm your ranking a little.

If you are only displaying your own tweets, or those of specific trusted accounts, then there is less need to add nofollow.